# Run headless Chrome or install it for Selenium use in VSTS

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run some chromedriver tests on VSTS using a Java + Maven project. Because I will be using Chrome extensions I am not able to run headless Chrome as it is not supported. I know that Chrome is, by default, not installed on the "Hosted VS2017" VM so I tried to install it via the following powershell script:

```
$Path = $env:TEMP; $Installer = "chrome_installer.exe"; 
Invoke-WebRequest "http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe" -OutFile $Path\$Installer; 
Start-Process -FilePath $Path\$Installer -Args "/silent /install" -Verb RunAs -Wait; 
Remove-Item $Path\$Installer
```

However, this results in the following error:

> 2017-11-06T01:23:18.4054541Z ##[command].
>   'd:\a\1\s\install_chrome_win.ps1'  2017-11-06T01:23:23.6299793Z
>   Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: This
>   operation requires an interactive window station.
>   2017-11-06T01:23:23.6299793Z At D:\a\1\s\install_chrome_win.ps1:1
>   char:‎169 2017-11-06T01:23:23.6299793Z + ... $Installer; Start-Process
>   -FilePath $Path\$Installer -Args "/silent / ... 2017-11-06T01:23:23.6299793Z +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   2017-11-06T01:23:23.6299793Z     + CategoryInfo          :
>   InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
>   2017-11-06T01:23:23.6299793Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
>   2017-11-06T01:23:23.6309786Z   2017-11-06T01:23:23.6559779Z
>
> ### [section]Finishing: PowerShell Script

Although I have specified the "silent" and "install" options it appears that there is still some kind of interactive input necessary.
I know that there is a .NET tutorial online which allows running of chrome tests but I cannot use it as I have a Java + Maven project.

My questions are:
1. Is it possible to get the "Hosted VS2017" VM to run Java selenium chromedriver "non-headless" tests?
2. What extra configurations do I have to make to get the above powershell script working? Is there a better script I should use instead?

Answer (score 2):

The hosted build agents have Selenium capabilities pre-installed. Instead of executing the installer, you can use the existing browsers by accessing the environment variables to get the path to the executables.

From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-selenium):

> When using the Hosted agent, you should use the Selenium web drivers that are pre-installed on the hosted agents because they are compatible with the browser versions installed on the hosted agent images. The file paths to these drivers can be obtained from the environment variables named `IEWebDriver` (Internet Explorer), `ChromeWebDriver` (Google Chrome), and `GeckoWebDriver` (Firefox). For example,
>
> ```
> driver = new ChromeDriver(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ChromeWebDriver"));
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can run Java headless chrome selenium test on an agent with service mode, but the chrome isn’t installed on Hosted agent and you can’t install it on the Hosted agent.

So, I recommend that you can setup a private build agent with Chrome installed and run Java Selenium on that agent.

Simple code of headless selenium test:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "[chromedriver.exe path]");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("headless");
        //options.setBinary("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"); 
        ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
          searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
          searchBox.submit();
        driver.quit();
```

On the other a uservoice about [Install headless chrome on hosted build servers](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/19387174-install-headless-chrome-on-hosted-build-servers).

Comment: Setup a private build agent, huh...Well as stated in the question the requirement was for VSTS since there aren't associated costs.

Comment: Oh also forgot to mention...It can't be headless since I need to run it with a Chrome extension :(

Comment: @starmandeluxe With this scenario, you need to setup a private build agent with interactive mode (Not service).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately this defeats the purpose of using a unit test in VSTS since it takes us back to square one by managing the agent ourselves.

Comment: Private build agent is the official way for the build can't do in hosted agent and it's easy to manage